# Vue.js 2.0 main instance

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How do I get a `boolean authenticated` on the main instance in `vue.js 2.0`?

Right now I've got this:

```
const app = new Vue({
    router,
    render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app');
```

Then in my `App` component:

```
data() {
    return {
        authenticated: false
    }
}
```

But it's not set on the Root component. So I cannot access it through:

```
{{ this.$root.authenticated }}
```

In my childcomponents (for example Navigation). How can I fix this. In `vue.js 1.0` this was working!

[image]

Comment: Maybe it's better to handle this with one separated file and vue-router - Check this https://github.com/TahaSh/spa-forum/blob/master/resources/assets/js/main.js#L56 even if this is vue 1 repo.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But then I still cannot show for example the ```user name```  that's on a user object on my ```main app.vue``` instance in the ```navbar```. I really need to solve this.

Comment: What you have in your root instance ? If you want to send user name to Navigation component, you can send it from anonymous component as prop, and just display it. Make sense ? I think you don't need the authenticated property in Root instance.

Comment: Yes, I understand. Sometimes I've got a ```component``` within a ```component```. So then I've to pass a ```prop``` from one component to the other and that component will pass it to another component. That's not how I would like to do it :)

Comment: I don't really get the point.Even if you have this data in Root instance, you still have to pass it down as prop to another component (for e.g navigation) if you want use it here.

Comment: No, because then I could simply do ```{{  this.$root.user.name }}``` in my templates. In a lot of templates I've to check if the user is authenticated. If so then I show something otherwise I don't. So in vue.js 1.0 I could just simply do ```v-if="this.$root.authenticated"```.

Comment: Okay, did you simply tried to include data object in main root instance ?

Comment: Yes, in my question you can see how I've done this. So I bind to a main ```App``` instance. And there I've got a data object with the ```authenticated``` attribute. Do you understand my problem?

Comment: I mean here `const app = new Vue({
    router,
    render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app');`

Comment: Nope, I did not :-). That fixed my problem! Thank you really made my day! Did not know that was possible.

Comment: Cool ! I was not sure about this but, this is standard Vue instance, so it should be able to accept the data object as usual.

Comment: Please post your answer like an answer and I will accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to define data object on root Vue instance.Like this:

```
const app = new Vue({
    data: {
      msg: 'foo'
    },
    router,
    render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app');
```